# Bitvise SSH Server putting extra spaces in session

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, zsh, bitvise

I am using Bitvise SSH Server on my Windows machine for remote access. The login shell is ZSH, and I am using Oh My Zsh with it. However, I have also tried BASH and got the same problem. Therefore I guess this problem is with Bitvise SSH Server, not my Cygwin shells or the client-side terminal emulators.

The problem can be noticed on the prompt of my ZSH. As long as my SSH session go through this Bitvise SSH Server, there will be some extra spaces in the prompt. Please see the screenshots:

[image: Differences between a session that goes through Bitvise and one that doens't]

This windows is the MinTTY on that Windows machine. When I open it you can see there is only one trailing space after `~` (before I type `ssh 127.0.0.1`). However once I SSH-ed into the same machine, there are two trailing spaces after `~` in the prompt. Also, if I do another SSH session (to the `tiger` machine) within the Bitvise SSH session, the prompt of the second one is also having extra spaces (red underlined prompts). However if I exit from the Bitvise session and SSH to `tiger`, directly, the prompt is normal (green underlined prompts).

I observed the same thing when connecting from some remote machine (using `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal` as the terminal emulator) to that Windows machine.

Therefore, my conclusion is, the terminal emulator is not to blame for this. The Cygwin and its ZSH are not to blame either, because everything looks good as long as I don't go through Bitvise.

My assumption is there's some special character defined in the Oh My Zsh theme that is not processed correctly when passing through Bitvise. However I couldn't find out what that is exactly. The Oh My Zsh themes look good locally without a Bitvise SSH connection, and they look good on all Linux machines I have. Therefore I think it should be something with Bitvise.

---

As suggested in the comments, I ran `set` in both environments, and got the outputs dumped into two text files: **bitvise.txt** and **local.txt**. Now the biggest issue is I cannot compare them using `diff` because `diff` claims they are binary files (and they differ). I am not sure if this has something to do with the weird spaces.

Forcing `LANG` on `diff` didn't help.

```
$ diff -uN bitvise.txt local.txt
Binary files bitvise.txt and local.txt differ

$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 diff -uN bitvise.txt local.txt
Binary files bitvise.txt and local.txt differ

$ LANG=C diff -uN bitvise.txt local.txt
Binary files bitvise.txt and local.txt differ
```

The two files are uploaded here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Pxoys5MF0Bc1d6QUMweUkybHc

---

Tested some different `TERM` settings... Didn't seem to do anything good. Setting `TERM=linux` resulted the same with `xterm`.

[image: Different TERM settings]

---

**Updated on 5/23/16**

The problem seems to be harder than I expected. I found a folder "C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Server\TermInfo" which contains the terminal info files. I replaced the files in that folder with the similar files I copied from a normal Ubuntu machine, but didn't help. I also tried the "cygwin" term info that is installed with Cygwin, no luck... Actually the "cygwin" file that comes with Cygwin is the same with the one that comes with Ubuntu...

I run out of idea now.

When I SSH into the Bitvise SSH Server, I can do `exec /bin/bash` to replace the current session with Bash. However in that Bash, if I SSH into some other Linux machine that uses Zsh and Oh My Zsh, the same problem persists.

Comment: use `set` to dump the full settings in the several cases. May be you can find a discrepancy

Comment: @matzeri Finally got time to do this... I did `set > local.txt` locally and did `set > bitvise.txt` in an SSH session to `localhost`. Now I got the two files, both very big and not exactly the same. However `diff` claims they are binary files so not outputting differences in lines... Still trying to figure out a way for this...

Comment: different locale ? see `man iconv` for conversion

Comment: @matzeri They don't seem to be different locales because they are both UTF-8 when I open them with Sublime Text... Are they just too big for `diff` (or too many differences)?

Comment: diff can handle huge files and all file different. If it complains about binary or your locale is not UTF8 or one of the caracther is not a valid UTF8. You can also try `LANG=C diff -uN file1 file2` or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 diff -uN file1 file2`

Comment: No, that didn't help. And I noticed `LANG` is the same in two environments, which is `en_US.UTF-8`. I added that to the question. I will try if I can upload these two files somewhere... @matzeri

Comment: @matzeri I uploaded the two files in a zip. If you have spare time maybe you can work on it? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Pxoys5MF0Bc1d6QUMweUkybHc

Comment: `diff -a -uN bitvise.txt local.txt |less` the only thing that seems relevant is `-TERM=cygwin  +TERM=xterm` .  Who is setting 'TERM=cygwin' for bitvise ?

Comment: @matzeri What I found with Cygwin is https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html. It says "The TERM environment variable specifies your terminal type. It is automatically set to cygwin if you have not set it to something else." I think usually the terminal software somehow sets `TERM`. For example, if I use PuTTY and specify the "terminal-type string" to "linux", then `echo $TERM` returns "linux"

Comment: @matzeri However, this "cygwin" is not changed even if I explicitly say to use "linux" or "xterm" in PuTTY... On the other hand, if I `export TERM=xterm` in the SSH session, the prompt becomes even worse. It outputs a `%` and newline before each prompt

Comment: @matzeri I found this guy https://plus.google.com/100791238593914710520/posts/RYtNH6jiBs4 talking about a similar issue, but copying terminfo from Ubuntu didn't help with my case.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that Oh My Zsh renders Unicode characters, and that the issue is that those characters have different widths in a Windows console.

For example, a character that has width 0 in MinTTY might have width 1 in the Windows console, and would advance the cursor. Or a character that has width 1 in MinTTY might have width 2 in the Windows console.

In the screenshots you've provided, you're looking at zsh with "Oh My Zsh" under MinTTY.

But what about in a Windows console? How does Oh My Zsh look there?

Bitvise SSH Server runs your terminal shell in a hidden Windows console, which is necessary to be able to run Windows console programs. Due to this architecture, zsh has to look right in a Windows console in order to render properly via Bitvise SSH Server.

Comment: You may be right... Oh My Zsh does not look correct in the Windows console - but it also looks different with what I see in Bitvise session.

Comment: If the problem is with Windows console, is there any possible fix for it?

Comment: If Oh My Zsh does not look correct in the Windows console, this issue would likely have to be fixed by the maintainer of the Oh My Zsh project - assuming that they want to fix this. It may also be possible that the Oh 
My Zsh configuration can be changed to work around the issue, but I do not have experience to say if this is possible or not.

Comment: Is it possible you don't use Windows terminal but MinTTY or something else?

Comment: It would be theoretically possible but not a good architectural choice for a Windows SSH server that needs to provide access to Windows console mode programs, not least PowerShell. MinTTY does not work well with PowerShell, or with any type of advanced Windows console-mode program in general.

Comment: How about adding an option to let user decide? For example I do not use any Windows console programs myself.

Comment: You may already be able to do this if you configure the SSH Server to use the "dumb" terminal type using the bash shell. This can be configured in Advanced SSH Server settings: http://i.imgur.com/htJ0qU1.png The problem is that it's not enough to use the "bash" Shell access type in this case - you will most likely need to configure a custom shell access type that calls bash in a way such that it will render escape sequences to the standard output, instead of writing to the console. In other words, you need to run bash in the way MinTTY runs it. Using "dumb" terminal, the output is sent as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. Thought I didn't really solve this problem using "dumb" terminal, the answer itself pointed out where the problem is.

Comment: I don't know how to make "dumb" working, because if I set it to dumb, when I SSH into that machine, I couldn't input anything - I am not even sure if the terminal is still alive (PuTTY didn't say disconnected though)... Therefore I guess I simply cannot use "dumb" with the way I use ZSH in Windows console. MinTTY doesn't tell me how it invoked it so I got no idea for that...

Comment: The solution I finally came up with was to change the code page of the simulated Windows console to 437. It was 936 on my machine because my Windows local settings set non-Unicode chars to be interpreted as Simplified Chinese. If code page is set to 437, Oh My Zsh will be displayed correctly in Windows console.

Comment: And I posted an answer myself which shows how I solved it finally.

Comment: Very nice :-) I'm glad you were able to find this solution! Instead of the registry, note that you may also be able to change the way the terminal shell is started to execute "chcp" at the beginning. In this case you would need to use the "custom" shell access type, and use a terminal shell string like: cmd /c chcp 437 & c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l. Similarly, for the exec request prefix, you might use: cmd /c chcp 437 & c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c. But the registry approach sounds perfectly viable too. Unfortunately I can't upvote due to Stack Exchange site-specific reputation thresholds.

Comment: Anyway, we got this fixed! Thanks a lot for your explanation. `cmd /c` sounds easier because I am already using a custom shell for ZSH and in this way I don't need to touch the registry - haven't checked if it works though, maybe next time when I work on a new machine? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Four weeks later I finally figured out the problem myself. Thanks to [denis bider](https://superuser.com/users/597342/denis-bider) who seems to come from the support team of Bitvise SSH Server. His explanation of on how Bitvise runs shells in Windows console is the key to solve this problem.

It turned out the `$TREM` environment variable and `terminfo` files are irrelevant.

The problem I actually had was, the Oh My Zsh themes I am using have characters that are displayed in other ways in my Windows console. However, I found that it was actually because my Windows console code page is set to 936 (Simplified Chinese) because of my Windows local settings (for non-Unicode characters). I found that if I manually change my code page to 437 (U.S. English) in the Bitvise SSH session, the output becomes correct.

Then I realized that for U.S. users, they don't even have this problem at all!

Therefore, the solution is to set the default code page of the Bitvise SSH Windows console to 437. This can be done in Registry, more specifically, in key `HKCU\Console\Bitvise toterms.exe`, there is a `CodePage` to be set to 437 (decimal). I also removed `FaceName` because it doesn't sound necessary at all.

[image]

However, setting this alone is not enough, because I found everytime a Bitvise SSH session starts, the value is set back to 936. Therefore, I need to change permissions of `HKCU\Console\Bitvise toterms.exe` to deny writing access from Everyone. Steps: 1. Right click on "Bitvise toterms.exe", and click "Permissions...". In the dialog, click Advanced. In the new dialog, click "Add...", then input "Everyone". Finally, check the following permissions for denied as is shown:

[image]

In this way, Bitvise SSH Server itself will no longer be able to alter these values, and then I got the correct output form my Bitvise SSH sessions.

Finally, Oh My Zsh looks the same whether it passes through Bitvise SSH Server or not.

[image]